# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'moltens.sliders' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, frameworks

When trying to display content on a website from databases through Laravel, it returned the following error message:

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S02)
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'moltens.sliders' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `sliders`)

Previous exceptions:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'moltens.sliders' doesn't exist (42S02)

The databases are made in MySQL. Database name is moltens

[ENV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSrs9.png)

Comment: Table doesn't exists. Create it and fill it with some data :) Edit: probably you're connecting to the wrong database, as it is mentioned below.

Comment: `moltens` this is your database name? maybe u forgot to change configuration

Comment: How does your eniviroment file look

Comment: Check your .env file and look for database name.Check whether it is moltens or not.

Comment: can you share your code you have tried and you migration

Comment: Database name is moltens, and I'm trying to connect to the slider table, but it returned to connecting to sliders which doesn't exists

Answer (score 0):

Create new table or check this table is exist in your database or check your connection with database in .ENV file.